# .vscode folder in .java is not on the classpath of project

Tags: java

When I create a folder that I create my whole studies like that and i create a new java program, i got this error without .vscode folder. Why? What does the .vscode file do and fix this error? Thanks for help.

[image: VSCode screenshot]

I want to know what .vscode folder do? how can .vscode folder fix this situation?

Comment: From a quick web search leading to [the official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_workspace-settings): Workspace settings as well as debugging and task configurations are stored at the root in a .vscode folder.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that is just telling vscode where to look for your source files.

I'm not sure how you went about creating this project but I would suggest looking at the official documentation [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project) and following along with that.